# jquery ui tooltips modified to work on click only opens and closes one time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

jquery: 1.8.2
jquery ui: 1.9.1

I modified the default way of implementing a jquery ui tooltip so it would work on click instead of hover.

The 'a' tag is the thing you click to activate the tooltip, but not defined as a tooltip.  The tooltip & tooltip content are placed after the 'a' tag and hidden with css so you cant hover or see the content.

```
<a class="tooltip-click" id="tt3">asdf</a><span class="tooltip-tick" title="">&nbsp;</span>
<div class="tooltip-content">3</div>
```

In the tooltip implementation I use the "content:" attribute to grab the content of the div next to the tooltip definition, rather than using "title"

I also have a function inside the tooltip definition that closes the tooltip if you click the tooltip content.

```
$('.tooltip-tick').tooltip({
        position: { 
            my: "left+15 center", 
            at: "right center",
            using: function( position, feedback ) {
                        $( this ).css( position );
                        //function to close tooltip when content is touched                            
                        $('.ui-tooltip-content').click(function(){
                            $(".tooltip-tick").tooltip("close");
                        });   
        }},
        //the content of the div next to the tooltip instead of using title
        content: function(){
            return $(this).next().html();
        }   
    });
```

When the A tag is clicked it first closes any open tooltips, then opens the neccessary one:

```
$('.tooltip-click').click(function () {
        //first i close open tooltips
        if($(".ui-tooltip").length) $(".tooltip-tick").tooltip("close");
        //then open the tooltip next to the a tag                
        $($(this).next('.tooltip-tick')).tooltip('open');
    });
```

**Everything works, but only once.**
http://jsfiddle.net/Js8g6/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to set title-attribute of ".tooltip-tick" after closing the tooltip:

```
$(".tooltip-tick").attr("title", "");
```

The title is needed to open the tooltip, but somehow it will be removed after closing.

This is just a little work-around ;)

Comment: Great, thanks. It is a pitty they have not yet fixed it (at least in 1.11.2)

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I have found. With the added benefit of inhibiting the default hover for title.

```
    $(".help").tooltip({ 

         position: { 

             my: "left-1 top+20", at: "right top" 

         },  

         open: function( event, ui ) {

            $('.ui-tooltip').hide();

            $('.help').click(function() {

                   $('.ui-tooltip').fadeIn();

           });
        }
    });
```